# How to give a space between 'apple' and 'is ' in a code written in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have coded Apple is the favorite fruit of SP in python.

But in the output, I got: `Appleis the favorite fruit of SP`

Plz, help me to identify the mistake and tell me how to add a space between Apple and is.

The code is:

```py
hey = "hello world"
print(hey)
name = "sp"
food = "apple"
print(str(food) + "is the favourite fruit of " + str(name))
```

Comment: you are concatenating the strings without concatenating spaces in between them. try food + ' ' + 'is the favourite food of' + ' ' + name  as it same as mike mentioned.

Comment: Not directly related to the problem at hand, but you don't need to cast food and name to strings using str since they are already strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ["formatted string literals" (a.k.a. "f-strings", available since Python 3.6)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to make it easier on yourself:

```py
>>> f"{food} is the favourite fruit of {name}"
apple is the favourite fruit of sp
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like what the other answers suggest, you can use f-strings to join things together.
However, if you want to use the same method as in your question, you an do this:

```py
hey = "hello world"
print(hey)
name = "sp"
food = "apple"
print(str(food) + " is the favourite fruit of " + str(name))
```

The difference here is that there is a space before the word `is`,

so instead of being `"is the favourite..."` it becomes `" is the favourite..."`.

This will add a space just after `str(food)` and so there will be a space in between `apple` and `is`.

Hope this was helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

2 easy ways, first your food could be "apple ", or in your string, insert a space before + "is..., so " is....." In either case, you need to add a space.

Comment: Can you please provide me a picture of code. I'm sorry but I'm unable to understand it .

Answer (score 0):

You can use format printing here,

```py
hey = "Hello world"
print(hey)
name = "sp"
food = "apple"

print(f"{food} is the favourite food of the {name}")
```

output

```
Hello world
apple is the favourite food of the sp
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer for you is adding a space after the double quotes before the "s".

```
hey = "hello world"
print(hey)
name = "sp"
food = "apple"
print(str(food) + " is the favourite fruit of " + str(name))
```

The next step would be using commas instead of the "+" symbols to which a space is automatically made, and you won't feel like you have to define the data type.

```
print(food, "is the favourite fruit of",name)
```

The best answer that will be most useful in most situations is using an f-string where you type "f" before your string and then place curly brackets "{}" with your variables enclosed. I think you'll find this to be more comfortable and natural.

```
print(f'{food} is the favourite fruit of {name}')
```